# Automatically sort rows when data is changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my Google sheet, I have 2 columns, A and B, which I would like to sort descending by values of Column B. This I know can be done using `filter`/`sort` options in sheets. This works as expected but this is a manual step that should be repeated every time data in column B changes.

I would like all rows to be automatically sorted when data in Column B changes. Any ideas to do this?

Example of data in column A and B

```
Team    Score
Team A  13
Team C  12
Team B  11
Team D  5
```

Comment: An [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) script will enable you to identify when data in Column B changes, then use `sheet.sort(columnPosition, ascending)` ([doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#sortcolumnposition-ascending)) will sort your sheet by column. Don't be put-off by the "ascending" reference, you can specify ascending or descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this script to your sheet:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z");

function onEdit(e)  {
  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}]);
}
```

---

- `Sheet1` = name of the sheet
- `A1:Z` = range to be sorted
- `column: 2` = column B
- `ascending: false` = descending

Comment: I have an additional question. Lets say i need to sort the rows based on first the score and then the total number of goals. Like this:

Comment: I have an additional question. I need to sort the rows based on first the score (the solution you have) and then the total number of goals - lets say column 3 in this case. So if the score is equal I have to run a second sort that compare the number of goals . Any ideas ?

Comment: you can do it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66Sf.png or adding it one more time for different range separately